# JQuery .animate() complete function executing before completion

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

There is a container `div (#content)` with `10px` padding and its `content (#inner_content)`. I'm loading some new stuff via `ajax` (the new html contains everything in a `#inner_content div`) and replace #`content's` html with the new html.

While doing this I want the height of the container `div (#content)` to adjust to the height of the new content by animation. So I have set overflow: hidden for the container div and when I load new content, I get its height and animate the container div to the same height. All is good expect that sometimes the height is somewhat bigger `(10-20 pixels` maybe) than needed and that's causing trouble to the design.

So I put a complete function on the `.animate()` to set the height of the container `div` to '' (`auto`) after the animation has completed so that the height is correct. The problem is that the complete function runs immediately, the animation is skipped and the height becomes auto instantly. Here's the code:

```
$("#content").html(response); 
$("#content").animate({height: $("#inner_content").height()+"px"}, 300, function () {
$("#content").css({height: ''});
});
```

How can I solve this problem? I need the animation to be executed then the height set to auto (this causes a small 'gap' in the proccess because the div immediately gets 10-20px shorter but it's ok.

Comment: 300ms is not very much, probably that's why you see it "instantly"

Comment: Well, 300ms is not "instantly" either. I can see the animation being executed normally when I remove the complete function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, without any source code it's tricky, but my gut instinct is saying, for some reason, your `#content` and `#inner_content` divs are actually the same height (I'm guessing 0), which is causing the animation to execute instantly, thus firing the event immediately as well.

Are you able to provide any source?

I would recommend first playing with the `outerHeight()` method on the divisions and see what happens. Additionally, try turning off the `overflow: hidden` and instead try the following pseudo-code:

1. Load the new content in a hidden separate `div`
2. Get the height of the new content
3. Animate the current content
4. Update the current content with the new content

Comment: Thanks, I got an idea from your pseudo code and now I no longer need to set height to auto after a load. So.. problem solved.

Comment: Glad to hear things worked out okay. :)  Did you ever figure out what the original problem was?